# asp.net core docker + App Service On Linux

Tags: azure-web-app-service

According to the docs is now possible run an asp.net core docker container on a linux app service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-using-custom-docker-image

I created a simple asp.net core 1.1 web api and followed the steps to run it. On the log, it says my app started, but I can't access.
Anyone tried to run the same ?!

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

COPY src/WebApi/bin/Release/netcoreapp1.1/publish/ /root/

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

WORKDIR /root

ENTRYPOINT dotnet WebApi.dll
```

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Application Settings I added an entry called PORT and gave it the 5000 value. Let me know if that works.

Best of luck!